# Copy bash array to a variable which name is hold by another variable

Tags: bash, variable, array

There are many similar questions, but I didn't understand any answer as solution of the following problem:

I want to create a bash function which holds two arguments, first is a variable name and second is a search string (for a file search).

As a result, I want the variable name holding an array of the found files.

I have a directory containing following files:

- a.jpg
- b.tif
- c.jpg

The function is defined as:

```bsh
search-files--fill-array()
{
    local variable_name="${1}"
    declare -a eval ${variable_name}

    local search_string="${2}"
    echo "${search_string}"

    local nullglob_setting=$(shopt -p nullglob)
    shopt -s nullglob
    found_files=(${search_string})
    eval "${nullglob_setting}"

    eval ${variable_name}=(${found_files[@]})
}
```

but the last line results an syntax error. It should assign the array to the variable which was presented as first argument to the function, so the function is called:

```bsh
search-files--fill-array my_variable_a "*.jpg"
```

So the desired result should be that

```bsh
echo "${my_variable_a[@]}"
```

shows me the two files "a.jpg" and "c.jpg" as an array, i.e.

```bsh
echo "${#my_variable_a[@]}"
```

shall result "2".

If it wouldn't have to be an array, the solution would be to use following last line:

```bsh
eval ${variable_name}=\${found_files}
```

Without any success I also tried to use a while loop to form the new array from the old one, but this doesn't work too.

```bsh
eval ${variable_name}="\${found_files[@]}"
```

produces that `my_variable_a` holds a string but not an array.

### Background

Perhaps my approach is completely wrong.

To make it clear: I want to have filled some variables each with an array which holds the filenames of files found by globbing (always the same way with different search “strings”). I expect only files, without any respect of subdirectories and I have to get sure, the results are always reliably sorted.)

And I want to avoid redundant code.

The `shopt` part is necessary to assure, if no file exists in the current directory, the array is filled with zero entries, while without nullglob, there would be exact one entry with the content of the search “string“.

### Solution

As [Uncle Billy](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/570380/397896) suggested, I can use `declare -n var` here.

The working function:

```bsh
search-files--fill-array()
{
    declare -n function=$1
    local shopt_setting=$BASHOPTS
    shopt -s nullglob
    function=($2)
    [[ :$shopt_setting: = *:nullglob:* ]] || shopt -u nullglob
}
```

His proposed handling of resetting the `nullglob` causes the function to not include any `eval` anymore. You can read e.g. [this stackexchange post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17529220/why-should-eval-be-avoided-in-bash-and-what-should-i-use-instead) to get to know, why avoiding `eval` is worth considering.

Comment: I gave you another way to set `nullglob` only in the function; see updated answer. Though you should be asking a different question about it.

Comment: At first, I didn't see the advantage of your `nullglob` handling, but you brought me into line. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use variable references:

```
search-files--fill-array()
{
  typeset -n a=$1
  local s=$BASHOPTS
  shopt -s nullglob
  a=($2)
  [[ :$s: = *:nullglob:* ]] || shopt -u nullglob
}

prompt> touch foo.txt bar.txt
prompt> search-files--fill-array foo '*.txt'
prompt> typeset -p foo
declare -a foo=([0]="bar.txt" [1]="foo.txt")
```

`help declare` for more details (`declare` is a synonym of `typeset`).

---

> `declare -a eval ${variable_name}`

This will declare two arrays *local* to the function, one named `eval` and the other named with the content of `${variable_name}`. No matter what you assign the them, it will be lost after the function returns. Use `declare -g` to make them global.

> `eval ${variable_name}=(${found_files[@]})` => syntax error

Same as `echo foo=(bar)` => syntax error. `(` is a meta-character, it cannot be used anywhere, but only at the beginning of a command (eg. after `;`, `&&`, etc) or as part of the special syntax used when assigning to an array.

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn't understand `declare -n` before and reading `help declare` did help me less then reading your example code. So I rewrote my function using `declare -n`. I want to thank also for suggesting an alternative way of setting (and resetting) the nullglob option, but I really wonder, what is it's advantage over my solution, since it unsets nullglob afterwards instead of ressetting it to the status before?

Comment: "what is it's advantage over my solution?" less (i.e. no) evals and subshells, though you probably won't see any difference in practice.

Comment: At first, I didn't understand your `nullglob` handling correctly. Now I see the advantage of avoiding evil `eval`s. Thanks alot!

Comment: One way to test the `shopt` and enable it if it is not already `if ! shopt -q nullglob; then shopt -s nullglob'; fi`  Which applies to all the `shopt` option in bash, ... just my two cents.

Comment: @Jetchisel but how you restore it to its previous value? I don't think that `shopt -q nullglob; local wasset=$?; ...; [[ $wasset = 0 ]] || shopt -u nullglob` is any better than what I have now.

Comment: @UncleBilly I'm not saying that mine is better, I only said that there is another option, but here `if shopt -q nullglob; then shopt -u nullglob; fi`

Comment: You can avoid the testing of `$?` if the goal is just run a single command depending on the exit status of the previous test/command, again just my two cents...

Comment: The goal is to restore it (to whatever its previous value was) upon exiting the function. Unfortunately, there's no way to localize the options set with `shopt` (`BASHOPTS`), as there is for the options set with `set` (`SHELLOPTS`) (`local -`).

Comment: Right, but there is always a logic to test/check to do the task/goal.